# Copy information from main sheet to several others based on criteria

Tags: excel

Main Sheet: All (Begins at Column B and ends at Column N (Row 7))
What I want to do is to copy the rows to other sheets which meet the criteria listed:

- New (if Column I "New")
- PreOwned (if Column I "Pre-Owned")
- Sold (If Column J "Yes")
- Detail (If Column K "Detail")
- Tint (If Column K "Tint")
- On Hold (If Column K "Hold")
- Completed (If Column K "Completed"
- Body (If Column L "Body")
- Recon (If Column L "Recon")
- Wash (If Column L "Wash")

I've created all of these sheets as well as an Index being the first sheet with appropriate buttons for each sheet based on the criteria. Buttons work but now I just need to enter all information into the main sheet (All) and allow it to sort (copy) to the appropriate sheet.

Thank you,

Comment: Suggestion: record a Macro using the Macro Recorder in Excel. Do an autofilter on your Main sheet, filter on your criteria and copy the rows to the other worksheets. Next, look at the code and try adjusting it to your needs. Then, when you're stuck, come back and post your code and point out where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro with appropriate criteria and it'll handle the rest.
You will have to enter the information in the main sheet though.

Comment: Where can I look up how the easiest way? I'm not familiar with Macro, I'm great with excel otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that exactly but I attempted and heres what I got.

Comment: Sub CopyTo()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' COPY
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$J$28").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="NEW"
    Columns("A:J").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("New").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(5, 6, 294, 14).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A5").Select
    Sheets("All").Select
    Range("E40").Select
End Sub